# Taking the Address of a Temporary, with a Twist

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have a function `address_of`, which returns a `Pointer` (encapsulating a `shared_ptr`) to its argument. `address_of` needs to work on both lvalues and rvalues, so there are two versions of `address_of`: one accepting a reference and the other accepting an rvalue reference. Since taking the address of a temporary is a Bad Thing™, the rvalue version of `address_of` needs to perform a move-construct in order for the `Pointer` to actually own something. The implementation is straightforward:

```
template<class T>
inline Pointer address_of(T& value) {
    return Pointer(&value);
}

template<class T>
inline Pointer address_of(T&& value) {
    return Pointer(new T(std::move(value)));
}
```

And taking the address of a temporary works as expected:

```
Pointer p = address_of(Derived());
```

But when I test with the following code:

```
Base* object = new Derived();
Pointer p = address_of(*object);
```

GCC complains that the call to `address_of` is ambiguous:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘address_of(Base&)’ is ambiguous
note: candidates are: Pointer address_of(T&) [with T = Base]
note:                 Pointer address_of(T&&) [with T = Base&]
```

I was under the impression that unary `*` always returns an lvalue, in which case the rvalue version shouldn't even be considered. What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by reference decay: (correct term is "reference collapse")

```
template < typename T >
void f(T && t) { .... }

int x; f(x); // what is f()?
```

The answer to the question in the code is that f() is:

```
void f(T& && t) { .... }
```

Which because of reference decay turns into this:

```
void f(T& t) { .... }
```

As you can expect, this will of course be ambiguous with anything defined as:

```
template < typename T >
void f(T & t) { .... }
```

This might work (fixed version):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template < typename T >
struct pointer
{
  pointer(T& t) {}
  pointer(T&& t) {}
};

template < typename T >
pointer<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type> 
address_of(T && t)
{ 
  return pointer<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  pointer<int> o = address_of(x);
  pointer<int> p = address_of(5);
}
```

The reason being that this reference decay stuff only happens in functions that are templated on T.  In this case your pointer class is, but the constructors are not actually templates themselves and so T& is never a valid T for the T&& version.

The first version still had the same problem as your code since address_of was just using T as the template parameter for pointer.  We actually need the raw type.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Any thoughts on how to achieve the behaviour I *do* want?

Comment: @Jon - one.  Not positive it will work but I put it in my answer.

Comment: @Noah: Close, but no cigar. I get `Pointer<T>::Pointer(T&&) cannot be overloaded with Pointer<T>::Pointer(T&) [with T = Base&]`.

Comment: Because I forgot to remove the reference in T before using it to instantiate pointer<>.  Fixed.

Comment: That did it! I suspected it would be something involving `remove_reference` but I got pulled away and didn't have a chance to test it. Works like a charm.

Comment: You might put a static_assert in your pointer class that checks if T is a reference and pukes if so.  This would make the compiler error more sensible to others since the error they'll get if they do pass a reference as T is what you got about overloading.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but unnecessary for my purposes: the code that makes use of this feature is autogenerated and will not be touched by humans.